# Running cat inside a node script tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shell, ubuntu, cat

[This tutorial at this point in time](https://youtu.be/3iuQfwZetx0?t=513) runs `cat` inside a node script tag like this:

```
cat dist/fs-gist/{runtime-es5,polyfills-es5,main-es5}.js > fs-gist.js
```

This works fine if I run it directly on the command line in Ubuntu.

However if I `npm run c` from this script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "c":"cat dist/fs-gist/{runtime-es5,polyfills-es5,main-es5}.js > fs-gist.js",

  },
```

, this happens:

```
ole@mkt:~/Temp/fs-gist$ npm run c

> fs-gist@0.0.0 c /home/ole/Temp/fs-gist
> cat dist/fs-gist/{runtime-es5,polyfills-es5,main-es5}.js > fs-gist.js

cat: dist/fs-gist/{runtime-es5,polyfills-es5,main-es5}.js: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check the path from which you ran the command directly from terminal?
Maybe it's different from that path from where the npm script executes, thus giving you the file not found error

Comment: @RamarajaRamanujan yes I'm in the same project directory as `package.json`.

Comment: It works for me. Please check if the dist folder was created when you run the npm script. Also, check if all these commands yield results from the terminal: 
cat dist/fs-gist/runtime-es5.js,
cat dist/fs-gist/polyfills-es5.js.
cat dist/fs-gist/main-es5.js.
This is just to make sure all the files exist.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the issue?

Comment: No.  I did all the checks you mentioned, and it works when I run the command from the command line, however it does not work within the script.   I even added `pwd` to check that the script is being run from the right directory.  It still gives this error: `cat: dist/fs-gist/{runtime-es5,polyfills-es5,main-es5}.js: No such file or directory`  It looks like it does not understand the curly brace part of the command ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is an OS quirk. I tested on my Mac and it works.
If your target is a Linux machine, which I assume to be the case as you have mentioned you use Ubuntu, you can try this,

```
"scripts": {
        "c": "bash -c 'cat dist/fs-gist/{runtime-es5,polyfills-es5,main-es5}.js > fs-gist.js'"
    }
```

This ought to work.